# NA in categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, missing-data

A categorical column can be encoded using one hot encoding before it's used in a machine learning algorithm. If I care about prediction, is it generally better to

- impute NA with the most frequent category, or
- create a new column called "column1_na" that is True whenever column1 had a missing value?

Comment: The second strategy raises the question of what you put in place of the missing values. What's generally better is hard to say. Using the most frequent category amounts to saying that you have no real idea what the missing value should be; even then there are other strategies. Often in real data there is systematic structure to missingness. More optimistically,  techniques of multiple imputation attempt to predict likely substitutes for missing values according to the information in other variables. There are 879 questions under `missing-data` so look at highly voted answers under that tag.

Comment: Both methods--mode imputation and missingness indicator--are biased. If you care about accurate predictions, and validations, multiple imputation is still the way to go.

Comment: @AdamO I think this question cannot be answered for the information given. It is highly depending on the data and model used.

Comment: @hxd1011 Missingness indicators do not marginalize the model, and single imputation is anticonservative and causes overfitting. Plus mode imputation lacks generalizability because the mode may change when validating a model in a different sample, and the mode may be biased in a complete case analysis. These missing data methods are generally regarded as incorrect. The conditions under which they provide unbiased predictions are pathological, most of the time they are wrong. If one wants a method that works, multiple imputation is superior to most.

Comment: There are lots of imputation strategies ranging from the simple:  mean replacement to the more complex:  regression-predicted, and cold-deck imputation to the more advanced:  multiple imputation.  Each has their own pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about when to impute a specific value vs using a missingness indicator variable, it depends  on several factors:

1) The nature of missingness itself: Is the value missing completely at random (MCAR), missing at random (MAR), or not missing at random (NMAR)? If the answer is either MAR or MCAR, you are safe with probably imputing the value, although what process you use to impute those values may differ. If the value is NMAR, it may be safer to use a missingness indicator variable.

2) The amount of missingness: This may seem obvious, but if most (or barely any) of the variable values are missing, adding a missingness indicator probably adds little to no value to a machine learning algorithm that is trying to make some prediction. You may consider just not using the variable (column deletion) or removing those instances with missing values (row deletion- this also depends on how large your data set is though, so be careful).

3) Business context: In certain business contexts, a missingness indicator variable may capture not only a systemic problem or issue with how data is collected but actually some real truth about the population being studied. For example, if individuals who fail to fill out a particular subfield for a credit card form are more likely to default on credit cards because they just tend to be careless, the missingness itself would be helpful for an algorithm in helping to predict unsee instances.

Comment: Please check, you say "If the answer is either MAR or NMAR", here NMAR should probably be MCAR?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean create a new column that gives 1 if the column has missing value and gives 0 if the column has no missing value then it is still a common practice in machine learning.

I want to elaborate something about the reason that missing value arises.

Case 1: The reason may be random, then the missing value is non-informative so that we may also delete, impute by mean, impure by regression or performing EM algorithm for basic level.

Case 2: If the missing value is itself informative, we are interested in the missing values because it tells us something important in the model.

I hope it helps,